# Finding temperature at junction of rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

Let's say I have three tubs, from left to right Tub 1, Tub 2, Tub 3.

Tubs 1 and 3 are at 50 degrees Celsius and Tub 2 is at 10 degrees Celsius.

Tubs 1 and 2 are connected by a copper rod, and tubs 2 and 3 are connected by a brass rod.

So it looks like this:

(50) --(copper)-- (10) --(brass)-- (50)

I want to find the temperature of the middle tub after a long time (assuming no heat loss to surroundings). I want to use conservation of energy and $H = (kA/L) \Delta t$, but I'm just not sure how to compute this or set it up.

Would I do $ (T-10) = (k_{Cu} A_{Cu}/L_{Cu})(50-T) +(k_{Br} A_{Br}/L_{Br})(50-T) $, then solve for T. I'm not sure how to treat this.

Answer (score -1):

Heat continues to flow between the tubs through the conductors, from hotter areas to colder ones, until the temperature difference between them is (including the connectors) **zero**, i.e. they are all at the same temperature $T_e$ ([Zeroth Law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics)): full **thermodynamic equilibrium** has been reached and there's no more heat flow.

Because the system is adiabatic ($\Sigma Q=0$), we can write (initial state v. end state):

$$m_1cT_1+m_2cT_2+m_3cT_3=m_1cT_e+m_2cT_e+m_3cT_e$$

Assuming $m_1c=m_2c=m_3c$ ($m$ is water mass, $c$ water specific heat),

we get simply:

$$T_e=\frac{T_1+T_2+T_3}{3}$$

The nature of the connectors does not affect the end result, only the time needed to reach full thermodynamic equilibrium.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the tubs are equally full of water (each mass M) then it is just delta T of cold tub x M = delta T of the warm tubs x 2M.  Where delta T is T -10 for the cold an 50-T for the hot ones.  It does not matter what material connects the tubs in the long term, but the pipe with the highest conductivity will just cool that tub a little faster but eventually it will all even out.

The formulas you had with k A over L x delta T are for heat transfer rates but because the tubs are changing T you need a diff eqn to get the T as a function of time AND the flows are NOT equal, I don't think you use these equations for this type of question.

If you were keeping tub 1 at 50C forever and tub 2 at 10C forever, then you could calculate the heat transfer rate with your formulas!